# Mongokit no collection found error

Tags: python, mongodb, collections, mongokit, database

I'm trying to save an object to mongodb with Mongokit. For some reason I am getting a "Connection Error: no collection found", only for this particular class model, Game.

I have defined the `__collection__ = 'games'` and `__database__` parameters in the model, and registered the model with the connection, db.

When I call

```
g = db.Game()
g.save()
```

I get an error "no collection found". It works fine with other class models that I've defined, like User. I can't see anything that I'm doing wrong! Any suggestions?

Comment: The same problem I was facing. I updated the Mongokit and problem gets solved. Take it as suggestion and save the object after Mongokit update.